# Do evaluation between columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame as follow:

```
head(df)
##   Item  order_online  order_store
## 1  x           1.9      1.6
## 2  y           5.2      1.6
## 3  z           1.9      3.9
## 4  bh          1.4      4.1
## 5  hj          1.4      4.1
## 6  kj          1.3      1.4
```

I want to do evaluation between number of `order_online` and `order_store` and if value of `order_online` is bigger than `order_store` mark it as `online` and if `order_store` is bigger than mark it as `store` in a new column called market.

So something like this:

```
##   Item  order_online  order_store   market
## 1  x           1.9      1.6         online
## 2  y           5.2      1.6         online
## 3  z           1.9      3.9         store
## 4  bh          1.4      4.1         store
## 5  hj          1.4      4.1         store
## 6  kj          1.3      1.4         store
```

#### What I did:

I tried to subset the data frame like this:

```
# for online orders
all_order_online <- subset(df, order_online > order_store)
all_order_online <- cbind(all_order_online, market="online")

# for store orders
all_order_store <- subset(df, order_store > order_online)
all_order_store <- cbind(all_order_store, market="store")

# tried to melt
melt(all_order_online, all_order_store)
# gives: error id variables not found in data
```

any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `ifelse`:

```
df$market <- ifelse(df$order_online > df$order_store,"online","market")
```

Your question doesn't specify what happens if they are equal, but that could be handled as well.

Since you seem to be having difficulty running this, here is how we might provide a completely reproducible example that show how this code does precisely what you asked for:

```
#Read in a coy&pasted version of your example data
df <- read.table(text = "   Item  order_online  order_store
    x           1.9      1.6
                     y           5.2      1.6
                     z           1.9      3.9
                     bh          1.4      4.1
                     hj          1.4      4.1
                     kj          1.3      1.4",header = TRUE)

#Prove that it's exactly what you had 
> df
  Item order_online order_store
1    x          1.9         1.6
2    y          5.2         1.6
3    z          1.9         3.9
4   bh          1.4         4.1
5   hj          1.4         4.1
6   kj          1.3         1.4

#Show that `ifelse` alone generates what you want 
> ifelse(df$order_online > df$order_store,"online","market")
[1] "online" "online" "market" "market" "market" "market"

# Show how adding a column directly works
df$market <- ifelse(df$order_online > df$order_store,"online","market")

#Prove that it worked
> df
  Item order_online order_store market
1    x          1.9         1.6 online
2    y          5.2         1.6 online
3    z          1.9         3.9 market
4   bh          1.4         4.1 market
5   hj          1.4         4.1 market
6   kj          1.3         1.4 market
```

Obviously, I typed `"market"` rather than `"store"`.

Comment: should this be used with any other function? because it outputs this `[1] "market" "market" "online" "online" "online" "online" "online"
##    [8] "market" "online" "online" "online" "online" "market" "market"`

Comment: @RainMan Not when I run it, it doesn't. It produces exactly what you asked for.

Comment: sorry I am new to R, but using your code I did : `market <- ifelse(df$order_online > df$order_store,"online","store") cbind(df, market)` and it works. Thanks

Comment: @RainMan The `cbind` step is not necessary, and potentially dangerous. (`cbind` can do unexpected things depending on the combination of inputs)

Comment: I am not sure, if I run your code directly I get `[1] "market" "market" "online" "online" "online" `

Comment: @RainMan, it's supposed to be `df$market`, not `market`. There is no need for the `cbind`.